# check for repeating nulls in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql

I need to check duplicate value exist in DB by compare each fields of the record

```
FIELD1 F2 F3  F4
 1     -   -   -
 1     -   -   -
```

In this case it shows duplication record. How can I query this using SQL?

Comment: What is the code you are currently using?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? You've got tags for both...

Comment: You mean all columns are `null`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this. You can either use [`DISTINCT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) in your query, or make `FIELD1` a primary key (which would prevent duplicate values) or use a [`UNIQUE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) constraint.

Comment: I don't see `NULL` in the question but it appears in the title, which prevents the use of distinct or primary key...

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server**

If you need to check if there exists duplicate values in a table you can use this query.

```
-- Setup test data
declare @T table (field1 int, f2 int, f3 int, f4 int)
insert into @T values (1, null, null, null)
insert into @T values (1, null, null, null)
insert into @T values (2, null, null, null)
insert into @T values (2, 2, 2, 2)
insert into @T values (2, 2, 2, 2)

-- Fetch rows that are duplicates
select field1, f2, f3, f4
from @T
group by field1, f2, f3, f4
having count(*) > 1
```

Result

```
field1 f2   f3   f4
1      NULL NULL NULL
2      2    2    2
```

If you need to query the table and not get duplicates use this query

```
select distinct field1, f2, f3, f4
from @T
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the SQL Standards, `NULL`s `GROUP` together, therefore in context should be no different from any other value i.e.

```
SELECT FIELD1, F2, F3, F4, 
       COUNT(*) AS duplicate_tally
  FROM YourTable
 GROUP 
    BY FIELD1, F2, F3, F4
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```